# OpenCL support for Ryzen 3 2200G in the latest kernel in 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: kernel, 20.04, amd-ryzen, opencl

Ever since the latest kernel updates in 20.04.1 LTS, the OpenCL support is lacking for my Ryzen 3 2200G Desktop. I use the OpenCL for certain applications in Bio-science applications. It was functioning very well before the last few (3-4) rapid kernel updates.
Can anyone advise how to get the OpenCL support. Its hampering my work.

I apologize for a very brief description of my problem, I assumed that people will be familiar with the absence of OpenCL support as it was the case when Ryzen 3 2200G was pretty new and the proper graphics support was unavailable till about kernel 5.0 series came to the ubuntu.

I use an application called UGENE which uses an Smith-Waterman algorithm that improves search speed in our genomics study. In absence of that the search speed degrades noticeably. The program while initializing, checks for OpenCL / Cuda support and reports it. Since last few kernel updates, it doesn't detect it. I used darktable to confirm the absence of the OpenCL.

Earlier when there was lack of proper support for the processor, I had to use amdgpu from AMD's website(Radeon™ Software for Linux® Driver for Ubuntu) to run it. But when kernel started supporting it, i uninstalled it as it used to break my graphics driver everytime i updated kernel.

I don't recollect the last kernel update which worked as I keep on updating weekly using synaptic manager. It may be 4 minor updates back, when things worked fine.

I hope this was descriptive enough and hopefully did not confuse you all.
Thanks for your efforts to answer my query.

Comment: You haven't given us *any* specifics or details about your problem.  I suggest that you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1292917/edit) your question and provide more details.  What evidence do you have that the latest kernel updates causes your problems?  What exactly are your problems?  You didn't even tell us which applications you are using!  We can't do very much without any details.  Help us help you.  The better you can document your issue, the more likely someone will be able to understand it enough to try to answer.

Comment: You can use an older kernel that still works for you until the issue is fixed, or you can bisect the kernel to find the problematic kernel commit and feed that information upstream. Kernel bi-section typically takes me about 2 days elapsed time. Note that 2 out of 3 times, once the problematic commit is known, one can also find that the issue is already known and a fix is in progress, but will take another month or more to propagate.